# Dropdown text Javascript suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

My javascript suddenly stopped working and I'm not sure why. I have a code that has a clickable title text, which then reveals another text below it. Could you guys take a look and let me know what happened? Here's a simplified version of the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#locations li span").click(function (e) {
    
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('show-dropdown') ) {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('show-dropdown');
    }
    else {
      $("#locations li").removeClass('show-dropdown');
      $(this).parent().addClass('show-dropdown');
    
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#locations .title:hover {
   cursor: pointer; 
}

li .appear {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
}
.show-dropdown .appear {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="locations">

<li>
<span class="title">Title 1</span>
<div class="appear"> Dropdown 1
</div>
</li>

<li>
<span class="title">Title 2</span>
<div class="appear"> Dropdown 2
</div>
</li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Your code is working. Check if you are calling for jQuery at your header, maybe someone might have removed it.

Comment: Check you console logs as well.